# Proving set is equicontinuous using compactness

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Consider the space $C([0, 1])$ of continuous functions $f : [0, 1] → R$ with
the supremum norm. Define the set $S$ by
$$S = {f ∈ C([0, 1])| 0 ≤ f'(x) ≤ 1, f(0) = 0, ∀x ∈ [0, 1]}$$
Prove that $S$ is equicontinuous.

I know that if S is compact in the sup-norm metric, then S is equicontinuous, but I am not sure how to prove compactness.

Comment: No, that's too easy of an approach; usually you use Arzela-Ascoli the other way, to *get* compactness by *checking* boundedness+equicontinuity. In this problem you need to proceed directly, specifically you need to explain how knowing that $|f'(x)| \leq 1$ gives you a uniform modulus of continuity which does not depend on the particular $f$ that you're dealing with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to show that a family of functions $\mathcal A$ is equicontinuous you need to show that given $\epsilon>0\exists \delta>0$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon $ whenever $|x-y|<\delta$ for all $f\in \mathcal A$

Note that For any $f\in S$; $|f(x)-f(y)|=|f^{'}(c)||x-y|\le |x-y|$

Can you find a uniform $\delta >0$ for all $f\in S$ from here ?

Comment: You used Mean Value Theorem correct? And you would choose delta to equal epsilon right?

Comment: You are absolutely correct.Bingo!

Comment: Any more doubts?You can consider accepting it if you like@3141